# using az functionapp start --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup in Automation Runbook

Tags: azure, automation, command-line-interface, runbook

We are looking at using az functionapp start --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup in Automation Runbook. As part of documentation its clearly stated that Azure CLI commands are supported in Automation runbooks, however not able to see this CLI command.

1. When trying to use below commands its throwing error that az is not recognized in internal or external command in Automation Runbook test. Can you please suggest sample code and references of modules.
2. Could not see az functionapp start command in Az help module under Azure RunBook API.

Out task is to start and stop azure functions through Automation Runbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Automation account does not support Azure CLI.
You can check Feedback here-
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/31482895-add-support-to-automation-for-az-cli

Comment: No I have checked it , please check

Comment: It Supports Powershell Az Module and Not CLI. In first line they have mentioned **Azure Powershell Az Module**

Comment: Would like to know if there are is azure powershell api support for starting and stopping azure functions. Its available with azure cli with below API:

az functionapp start --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup

if its not available would there be any way to run above command through azure Automation runbook.